# Java SAX Parser - NumberFormatException while parsing int

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I'm try to parse an XML by SAX Parser which looks like that:

```
<fil:films xmlns:fil="http://filmrenting.nure.ua/films/" xmlns:film="http://filmrenting.nure.ua/entity/film/">
  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
  <film:film id="3">
    <film:name>Matrix</film:name>
    <film:year>1999</film:year>
    <film:genre>SciFi</film:genre>
    <film:duration>PT110M</film:duration>
    <film:ageRating>NC-17</film:ageRating>
    <film:mediaCarrier>DVD</film:mediaCarrier>
    <film:description>Movie with Keanu Reeves!</film:description>
    <film:price>120.5</film:price>
  </film:film>
  <film:film id="5">
    <film:name>Dark Knight</film:name>
    <film:year>2008</film:year>
    <film:genre>Horror</film:genre>
    <film:duration>PT127M</film:duration>
    <film:ageRating>R</film:ageRating>
    <film:mediaCarrier>BD</film:mediaCarrier>
    <film:description>A movie about Batman, directed by Christopher Nolan!</film:description>
    <film:price>160.99</film:price>
  </film:film>
</fil:films>
```

A piece of SAX parser is shown below:

```
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        ...
        if (Const.TAG_YEAR.equals(current)) {
            try {
                film.setYear(Integer.parseInt(new String(ch, start, length)));
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

And I get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
    "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at ua.kiu.si.film.parser.SAXParser.characters(SAXParser.java:79)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.characters(AbstractSAXParser.java:546)
    ... (other errors)
```

There is no newline symbols somewhere in the field, but it still points at it. It successfully outputs the 1st name (Matrix), but then gets stuck with that error. DOM parser, however, parse the XML just fine.

How to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you add some prints so you can see precisely where in the input the error occurs?

Comment: Is it necessary to use a SAX parser?

Comment: @AndyMan, I wrote about it. It successfully outputs the first line, but give an error while parsing the first possible int.
Unfortunately, yes, but I hope I won't implement such bizarre things ever again.

Comment: Perhaps that is the new line before <film:year>?

Answer (score 1):

SAX parsers are allowed to split text nodes anywhere they like, reporting the content in multiple consecutive calls of the characters() interface. Your code is assuming that the value will not be split in this way.